# Describe and Info for SFrame

Tags: python, pandas, sframe

It would be nice to see summary of the [SFrame](https://github.com/turi-code/SFrame), something similar to what pandas DataFrame gives you with methods `.info()` and `.describe()`

What is the easiest way to do this except `sf.to_dataframe().info()`, `sf.to_dataframe().describe()`  ?

UPD: Where SFrame is DataFrame implementation by Turi, that has less functionality than pandas, but significantly faster. https://github.com/turi-code/SFrame

Comment: What is SFrame is it a `Series` or `Dataframe`.Please clarify your question its not clear.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for `sf.show()`, which launches an interactive Canvas window allowing you to also see basic data visualizations like scatterplots, lineplots etc besides the summary stats.

One caveat here the `show()` function is only available in the commercial version of graphlab create. So you will not have access to it if you're only working with their opensource sframe (and not the entire graphlab create package). This translator link might help you https://turi.com/learn/translator/#Computing_statistics_with_data_tables

Hopefully folks from Turi (previously Dato) should change this.